# ubuntu 18.04 locks itself after 5 mins from logging even if working

Tags: lock

I had installed ubuntu 18.04 on my del inspiron lap.
when I logging in and work it returns to lock screen after 5 minutes even if I am working.

Comment: I would boot up the machine using the Ubuntu LiveCD or USB equivalent ... if it works OK then then your issue is software related ... if it still locks well then I'd say its some hardware fault ... give this experiment a go and let us hear back